# Python script that asks the user to enter a DNA sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

CONTINUED

Prints `"Invalid"` once if it contains letters other than A, C, G, and T. Otherwise `"Valid"` just once.
For example if the user types in ACCFG the program should output should  be `"Invalid"`

I have this - What is wrong?

```
dna=raw_input(“your dna sequence:”)
for char in raw_input:
   if raw_input(char)!=”A”and”C”and”G”and”T”:
       print Invalid
   else:
       print Valid
```

Comment: you should look into (Biopython)[http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page]. All of this is done for you in that package.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
dna=raw_input(“your dna sequence:”) # Read line
for char in dna: # Iterate over all characters in dna
   if char not in [”A”,”C”,”G”,”T”]: # If the character isn't one of [”A”,”C”,”G”,”T”]
         print ”Invalid”
   else:
         print ”Valid”
```

If you only want to print it once, make it as:

```
dna=raw_input(“your dna sequence:”) # Read line
correct = "Valid"
for char in dna: # Iterate over all characters in dna
   if char not in [”A”,”C”,”G”,”T”]: # If the character isn't one of [”A”,”C”,”G”,”T”]
       correct ”Invalid”
       break
print correct
```